# How to do regex split and replace on dataframes columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

QUESTION: Is there a function to simplify this whole process?

So I was trying to clean data.
Data source: [UN Energy Table](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/environment/excel_file_tables/2013/Energy%20Indicators.xls) (will automatically download xls file) And the data in question is the 'Country' column after this xls is turned into a dataframe.

[image: Picture of dataframe head bcs I can't add pics yet:)]

The task was to remove the parentheses and numbers attached on the Country name. What I did was, find all country names containing numbers or parentheses, turning it into a list, finding the clean name and replacing them one by one through a loop.

```
# Finding all dirty country names 
dirtyNames = df1[df1['Country'].str.contains('[A-Za-z ][0-9/(/)]')==True] 
# Changing them to list
dirtyNames = dirtyNames['Country'].tolist()

for name in dirtyNames:
    clean = re.split('[0-9/(/)]', name)[0]
    df1.replace(name,clean, inplace=True)
```

but is there a function for this? I feel like there must be a function for it if I have to make a loop.
I tried examples from the internet, fixing my dataset into these,

```
df['first_five_Letter']=df['Country (region)'].str.extract(r'(^w{5})')
```

and other similar methods, but I keep getting the **AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!** error.

Comment: Are there NaNs in you data? Or any other non-string values in "Country" column?

Comment: Some sample data would make it a lot easier to answer this question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does [this code](https://pastebin.com/3QE6g0u4) work as you expect?

Comment: @pavel Oh yeah I'll double check. I didn't think about that. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick thanks for the suggestion, I added the data source!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes!

Comment: Great, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very straightforward way of doing it by chaining regexes.

```
s=[Some list of Countries with numbers and parentheses]
for i,x in enumerate(s):
    s[i]=re.sub("[0-9]", "", (re.sub("\)","",(re.sub("\(", "", s[i])))))
```

or

if 's' is a column in dataframe 'df',

```
for i,each in df['s'].iteritems():
    df.loc[i,'s'] = re.sub("[0-9]", "", (re.sub("\)","",(re.sub("\(", "", df.loc[i,'s'])))))
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you did. But then I also had to get rid of the text inside the parentheses... But thanks for the idea, I'll try to look into chaining regexes!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['XXX(12)', 'YYYY5000', '(ZZZ)15', np.nan]})
 
df.loc[pd.isna(df['Country']), 'Country'] = ""
df['Country'] = df['Country'].astype(str).str.replace(r'[0-9()]+', '', regex=True)
df.loc[df['Country'] == '', 'Country'] = np.nan
```

Here,

- `df.loc[pd.isna(df['Country']), 'Country'] = ""` - converts all `NaN` values to empty strings
- `.astype(str)` - converts data to string type
- `.str.replace(r'[0-9()]+', '', regex=True)`  - removes all digits, `(` and `)` chars
- `df.loc[df['Country'] == '', 'Country'] = np.nan` - converts empty strings back to `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove both numbers or text in parentheses (or possibly both, but with the numbers always at the end) at the end of the string with nothing, you can do that with one regex replacement:

```py
df = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', skiprows=17, usecols='C:F',names=['Country', 'Supply', 'per Capita', 'Renewable'], skipfooter=38)
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace(r'(?:\s*\(.*\))?\d*$', '', regex=True)
```

Tested on the actual dataset, this gives for `df['Country']`:

```
[
 'Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'American Samoa', 'Andorra',
 'Angola', 'Anguilla', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Argentina', 'Armenia',
 'Aruba', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Azerbaijan', 'Bahamas', 'Bahrain',
 'Bangladesh', 'Barbados', 'Belarus', 'Belgium', 'Belize', 'Benin',
 'Bermuda', 'Bhutan', 'Bolivia', 'Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba',
 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Botswana', 'Brazil', 'British Virgin Islands',
 'Brunei Darussalam', 'Bulgaria', 'Burkina Faso', 'Burundi', 'Cabo Verde',
 'Cambodia', 'Cameroon', 'Canada', 'Cayman Islands', 'Central African Republic',
 'Chad', 'Chile', 'China', 'China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region',
 'China, Macao Special Administrative Region', 'Colombia', 'Comoros', 'Congo',
 'Cook Islands', 'Costa Rica', "Côte d'Ivoire", 'Croatia', 'Cuba', 'Curaçao',
 'Cyprus', 'Czech Republic', "Democratic People's Republic of Korea",
 'Democratic Republic of the Congo', 'Denmark', 'Djibouti', 'Dominica',
 'Dominican Republic', 'Ecuador', 'Egypt', 'El Salvador', 'Equatorial Guinea',
 'Eritrea', 'Estonia', 'Ethiopia', 'Faeroe Islands', 'Falkland Islands',
 'Fiji', 'Finland', 'France', 'French Guiana', 'French Polynesia', 'Gabon',
 'Gambia', 'Georgia', 'Germany', 'Ghana', 'Gibraltar', 'Greece', 'Greenland',
 'Grenada', 'Guadeloupe', 'Guam', 'Guatemala', 'Guernsey', 'Guinea', 'Guinea-Bissau',
 'Guyana', 'Haiti', 'Honduras', 'Hungary', 'Iceland', 'India', 'Indonesia',
 'Iran', 'Iraq', 'Ireland', 'Isle of Man', 'Israel', 'Italy', 'Jamaica',
 'Japan', 'Jersey', 'Jordan', 'Kazakhstan', 'Kenya', 'Kiribati', 'Kuwait',
 'Kyrgyzstan', "Lao People's Democratic Republic", 'Latvia', 'Lebanon',
 'Lesotho', 'Liberia', 'Libya', 'Liechtenstein', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg',
 'Madagascar', 'Malawi', 'Malaysia', 'Maldives', 'Mali', 'Malta', 'Marshall Islands',
 'Martinique', 'Mauritania', 'Mauritius', 'Mexico', 'Micronesia', 'Mongolia',
 'Montenegro', 'Montserrat', 'Morocco', 'Mozambique', 'Myanmar', 'Namibia',
 'Nauru', 'Nepal', 'Netherlands', 'New Caledonia', 'New Zealand', 'Nicaragua',
 'Niger', 'Nigeria', 'Niue', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Norway', 'Oman',
 'Pakistan', 'Palau', 'Panama', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Paraguay', 'Peru',
 'Philippines', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Puerto Rico', 'Qatar', 'Republic of Korea',
 'Republic of Moldova', 'Réunion', 'Romania', 'Russian Federation', 'Rwanda',
 'Saint Helena', 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', 'Saint Lucia', 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon',
 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', 'Samoa', 'Sao Tome and Principe',
 'Saudi Arabia', 'Senegal', 'Serbia', 'Seychelles', 'Sierra Leone',
 'Singapore', 'Sint Maarten', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Solomon Islands',
 'Somalia', 'South Africa', 'South Sudan', 'Spain', 'Sri Lanka', 'State of Palestine',
 'Sudan', 'Suriname', 'Swaziland', 'Sweden', 'Switzerland', 'Syrian Arab Republic',
 'Tajikistan', 'Thailand', 'The former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia',
 'Timor-Leste', 'Togo', 'Tonga', 'Trinidad and Tobago', 'Tunisia', 'Turkey',
 'Turkmenistan', 'Turks and Caicos Islands', 'Tuvalu', 'Uganda', 'Ukraine',
 'United Arab Emirates', 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland',
 'United Republic of Tanzania', 'United States of America', 'United States Virgin Islands',
 'Uruguay', 'Uzbekistan', 'Vanuatu', 'Venezuela', 'Viet Nam',
 'Wallis and Futuna Islands', 'Yemen', 'Zambia', 'Zimbabwe'
]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, this worked! By the way, I tried looking it up but couldn't really get it through my head. What does the 'usecols' parameter actually do? I tried and it works without it, so I was just wondering what it actually does.

Comment: @Tamy `usecols` tells pandas which columns to take from the Excel spreadsheet, in this case the data is in columns C to F so we specify that using Excel notation of `C:F`